# Rails ORM query results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4

Why doesn't the Ruby on Rails framework provide a method to understand if an operation I'm doing will cause a query or not?

Take a User that has many Posts

in my view I will do:

```
<% @user.posts.each do |p| %>
  <%= p.title %>
<% end %>
```

I have no way to see if in my controller I did

```
@user = User.find(params[:id]).includes(:posts)
```

that is an eager loading, and causes one query, with a left join, or if I did:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

that causes n+1 queries

If the application is simple, there wouldn't be any problem, but let's take a larger application.
Maybe the query method is not in the controller, but in the model. And maybe it's not even in the model, but in a concern (an external module, included my the model).

in other words I have the impression of losing control of what the framework is doing with my database.

Did you find any solutions for this problem?

Comment: You can add bullet gem in your application which will prompt for n+1 queries

Comment: Actually, `includes` does not cause one query with a left join but two queries. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Also you may use this gem to help you: https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet

Comment: I know bullet gem, but it's not enough. I don't want a diagnostic, I want a structured work method. Something like 'put all the query results in an array, so that I can't call the database transparently'. A framweork should provide methods to resolve very common problems, and I can't believe this is not a common problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add bullet gem in your application which will prompt for n+1 queries

Add this gem in your application

```
gem "bullet", :group => "development"
```

Add below settings in your configuration file config/environments/development.rb

```
config.after_initialize do
  Bullet.enable = true
  Bullet.alert = true
  Bullet.bullet_logger = true
end
```

After that you should be able to monitor n+1 queries

More reference can be checked in below link

https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet